# hexbin savefig loses gid if rasterized=True

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below code will write svg file with svg tag with id="element", which is fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.standard_normal(10000)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(10000)

plt.hexbin(x,y, cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r,gid="element")
plt.savefig("img.svg")
```

But if I add **rasterized=True** flag to *hexbin()*, gid is lost after rasterization process, and img.svg < image tag contains some random tag id (like < image id="image9f9a4ebdcc"...).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.standard_normal(10000)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(10000)

plt.hexbin(x,y, cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r,gid="element",rasterized=True)
plt.savefig("img.svg")
```

It is possible to somehow keep hexbin gid in an output image tag?
Thanks

**UPDATE** little hack to work around

```
def saveFile(self,filename):
    """
        save svg with updated image tag id's
    """
    data = StringIO()
    self.fig.savefig(data,format='svg',transparent=True)
    data.seek(0)
    img = minidom.parse(data)
    it=0
    for i in img.getElementsByTagName('image'):
        i.setAttribute('id','img_'+self.gids[it])
        it+=1
    fw = open(filename,"w")
    img.writexml(fw)
    fw.close()
    data.close()
    img.unlink()
```

Comment: please create an issue on github.  Smells like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks, I just created new issue at matplotlib github.